# Couldn`t connect to helper in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Trying add default helper in Codeigniter, type in autoload `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` But i have an error `Unable to load the requested file: helpers/_helper.php` on my system/helpers folder there is no such file like `_helper.php` what i shoul do to load it?

Comment: "what i shoul do to load it?" Create the file to load it. But I feel that this is not what you want. So please take a minute to reformat your question.

Comment: i mean, may be i do something wrong? i download coedeigniter from theyr site... put application folder to system.. i don`t delete anything... this is standart function... but why it doesn`t work?

Comment: Wait wait: what do you mean by "put application folder to system"? they should remain as you found them!

Comment: i always do that. I`m trying put application folder to one root level with sitem, but there is no changes... error still showing. Trying to add some other helpers not `url` only... but have no changes

Comment: I don`t know in what was a problem, but i rewrite autoload string to the same, and then all works good. You may close theme, thank you.

Comment: you have to check which version of codeigniter you are using because in codeigniter 2.0+ the application folder is no longer inside the system folder it should remain outside it.

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you have an empty array set to `$autoload['helper']` variable in application/config/autoload.php.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array(''); // throw an error stated
```

Replace it with

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

Even though I do not understand why it has to behave differently from the above two assignments, basically IMO it should behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you write `'url'`

Like this: 
`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Answer (score 0):

make sure the array is empty if your not going to pass in a url and if so this would ideal in passing in css stylesheet urls.