# why can't Codeigniterload Input class, and can't find the file either

Tags: post, include, codeigniter-2

Im trying to use codeigniters input class, to use the post method. Now then, I tried loading it in the controller and the autoloader but no luck! The error im getting is

```
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/input_helper.php
```

after I tried to find it by looking through my code looking for Input but the IDE couldn't find anything. I just want to essentially use

```
$this->input->post('varname');
```

nothing crazy. So, does this file not get included from codeigniter by default? I got the most recent release from github a few days ago. Im pretty new to codeigniter so if I say something stupid, please forgive me. An explanation would be very appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484480/couldnt-connect-to-helper-in-codeigniter). In your case, I think it would be the helper `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to load this helper at all: [Input Class Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

> Note: This class is initialized automatically by the system so there
>   is no need to do it manually.

Try removing any of your attempts to autoload in the controller or elsewhere, then try again and see if that works.

Comment: when I just try $this->input->post('varname');, I get this error:
Call to undefined function post()

Comment: Then it appears something is wrong with your configuration, as your install cannot find system/helper. Try downloading a fresh package into it's own new directory and try your call to input->post() function in the welcome controller. It should work, and if it does then that indicates that something odd must have been changed in one of your configuration files that is causing an error. This should "just work" with no configuration or loading effort on your part, and I confirmed that on my system it just works out of the box as the documentation states it ought to.

Comment: Okay, so apparently, one of my lines was $this->input-post('varname'); I was missing the > and so it gave me that error. Thanks for all your help though!