# Trying to build the simplest codeigniter captcha according to the codeignuter help instructions but it dosen't work

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

Trying to build the simplest codeigniter captcha according to the codeigniter help instructions but it dosen't work.

My controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class c_captche extends CI_Controller {


    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484480/couldnt-connect-to-helper-in-codeigniter
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TU_8b9SRe_k
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAmAxdSGZSs
     /*
        http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html

        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR3ODc0vDvA
        http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-create-captcha-with-codeigniter.html
        http://www.cecilieo.com/techblog/how-to-use-codeigniter-captcha-plug-in/
                     */
    public function  __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('image_lib') ;
    //$this->load->helper(array('captche'));
    $this->load->helper('captcha'); 

    }


    public function index() {

    echo "in c_captche";    
     $data = array(
    'word'   => 'Random word',
    'img_path'   => './captcha/',
    'img_url'    =>  base_url().'application/captcha/', 
     'img_width'     => '150',
    'img_height' => 30,
    'expiration' => 7200
    );

    $captch=create_captcha( $data);


print_r($captch);

$this->load->view('v_captche',$captch);

}
}
```

My view:

```
<?php


print_r($captch);

 echo $captch ;

?>
```

I created folder called captcha under application folder.
No image been created there.
The error msg i get is:

```
 PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: captch

Filename: views/v_captche.php

Line Number: 8

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: captcha

Filename: views/v_captche.php

Line Number: 9
```

But even before the error msg, no img is been created in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation :

```
The "captcha" folder must be writable (666, or 777)
```

So check your folder rights, and you have to create this folder at your index.php root.

Then, for your view, you should use :

```
$this->load->view('v_captche',array('captcha' => $captch));
```

And in your view :

```
print_r($captcha);

echo $captcha['image'];
```

Comment: Thak you.What does it mean "you have to create this folder at your index.php root"/ Iit not ok that it is under application folder ?Where shoyls it be ?

Comment: When i right click the folder i see that the "read only" in not checked.Is this enough for it to be  writable ?